# If div has (classname), check the checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to add some backend stuff. But i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

I've created my own code, if checkbox is checked, add class to div.

But, in my original code, i'd like to add the class already to the div. But when that class is already there, the checkbox isn't checked.

So my question will be: How can i add a simple piece of code to the JS i have already?

Below are my details and Fiddle is at the bottom.

HTML:

```
<input class="b" type="checkbox" name="blue" value="">Check me for B.
<input class="s" type="checkbox" name="silver" value="">Check me for S.


<div class="b h">
    Some text and divs etc.    
</div>    
<div class="s">
    Some text and divs etc.    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.b{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1em;
}
.s{
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 1em;
}
.h{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].b").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('div.b').addClass("h");
    } else {
        $('div.b').removeClass("h");
    }
}); 

$("input[type='checkbox'].s").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('div.s').addClass("h");
    } else {
        $('div.s').removeClass("h");
    }
});
```

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEC58/)

Any help will be nice ! D:

Answer (score 4):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].b").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('div.b').addClass("h");
    } else {
        $('div.b').removeClass("h");
    }
}); 

$("input[type='checkbox'].s").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $('div.s').addClass("h");
    } else {
      $('div.s').removeClass("h");
    }
});

function checkCheckboxes() {
    if ($("div.b").hasClass("h")){
        $("input[type='checkbox'].b").prop("checked", "true");
    }

    if ($("div.s").hasClass("h")){
        $("input[type='checkbox'].s").prop("checked", "true");
    }
}

checkCheckboxes();
```

Comment: nice one jonsuh. I tried to do .prop('checked', true); at a certain point, but now i see i needed to add "" around true... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/sha2S/)

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].b").prop("checked", $("div.b").hasClass("h"));
$("input[type='checkbox'].s").prop("checked", $("div.s").hasClass("h"));
```

---

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative way of doing it:
http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/LEC58/6/

JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $("input[type='checkbox'].b").change(function(){    
            $($(this).attr("data-target")).toggleClass("h");
    }); 

    $("input[type='checkbox'].s").change(function(){
            $($(this).attr("data-target")).toggleClass("h");
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<input class="b" data-target="div.b" type="checkbox" name="blue" value="" id="chkB">
<label for="chkB">Check me for B.</label>

<input class="s"  data-target="div.s"  type="checkbox" name="silver" value="" id="chkS">
<label for="chkS">Check me for S.</label>

<div class="b">
    Some text and divs etc.    
</div>    
<div class="s">
    Some text and divs etc.    
</div>
```

I trigger based on change, not click (not much difference, as long as it's not disabled).
You could also make it even more generic, using the same code for many checkboxes and using switch of if/else.

Comment: You're failing to understand what the OP wants. He wants the checkboxes to be checked/unchecked when the page loads, based on whether the divs have a certain class (or not).

Comment: Ah, ok :-) Sorry for my confusion.